# Frankfurt theme show total number of slides

Tags: beamer, themes

In the Frankfurt theme, beamer package, by default in the bottom right corner is shown the page number. How can I change this so that it not only shows the page number, but also the total number of pages (e.g. 5/30)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With package: 
`\usepackage{lastpage}`

you can have the number of the last page with
`\pageref{LastPage}`.

Answer (score 6):

By default, in `Frankfurt` theme, `footline` beamer-template is empty. In your preamble, try `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]` or `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]` (with some versions of `beamer` before 3.51, you must also fix the color used to typeset the page number or frame number).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
% \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=fg} % beamer version < 3.51
\begin{document}
\section{First}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Demo 1}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<+->first item
  \item<+->second item
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Demo 2}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<+->first item
  \item<+->second item
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This code isn't showing any page numbers on my system (pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)). Any idea why not?

Comment: @tparker I updated my answer...

Comment: Thanks, now it works! A bit silly that they now require a font color...

Comment: @tparker This bug is already fixed, see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/04b25165835abcbe39294c9f5d89c371c70ba8c3. Can you update to beamer version 3.51, available at https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer